# What counts towards the goal in Mallcrashers?

Tags: payday-2

In Mallcrashers, your goal is to destroy $50000 worth of property. I know destroying store glasses counts towards the goal. Destroying the glass railings seems to count, too.

What else counts towards it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can destroy lots of stuff:

- Mall's black and white signs
- Stores glasses
- Glass runways/railings
- Glass roof
- Glass shelves in some of the stores
- Wine bottles in the wine store
- Vases and poteries at the antique store
- Sport car's windows in the showroom
- Shoe box stacks (tip: directly shoot the top of the stack)
- Computers and headphones at the Pear store
- ATMs if you have a saw
- Clothing stores and gym can be burned down with a gas can (cf. mission's assets)

Note that trip mines can prove useful in this level: simply plant one in the middle of an area where you want to blast stuff (liquor bottles for instance) and shoot at it.

Comment: The computers and headphones in the "pear" store also count. So do the bags in the bag store. There are some other things as well, but I am not sure if they actually count.

Comment: Ah, I wondered about the stuff in the Pear store; ok I'll add that to the list, thanks for the hint !

Comment: +1 for shooting the tripmines. Can't believe i've never thought about that.

Comment: You can also steal and bag jewelry in that store (and take it with you at the end of the mission for extra $$).

Answer (score 8):

You can add gas cans to your assets in this mission which can be used to set the gym, clothing stores and a few other places I think on fire.

Answer (score 5):

Another good tactic, and one which will earn you the Steam achievement "Shoot the Glass!", is shooting the upper level windows upstairs. They are just below the skylight, and are panel glazed.

I also tend to shoot out all the black and white shop signs and mall brand signs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a car in the car show room. That counts too as well as a wine store where you can destroy glass bottles. I would like to know how does the gym and clothes stores count towards the total?

Comment: Do you need c4 to blow up the car or is shooting enough?

Comment: There is also a china/pottery shop that has vases that can be destroyed. I'd imagine those count towards the goal as well.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much everything that breaks counts toward your goal, If you place a trip mine in the "Pear Store" that will gain a lot of damage. Also the wine bottles in the liquor store, and the car in the showroom are all great ways to rack up the damage fast.